# write a dictionary into an xlsx file

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'4F703:00013:02038': {'100.000, Oryza rufipogon x Oryza sativa', '100.000, 
    Oryza rufipogon', '100.000, Oryza sativa', '100.000, 
    Oryza sativa Japonica Group', '100.000, Oryza sativa f. spontanea'}}
```

And I want to write this dictionary into an xlsx file, so I did this code:

```
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet()
row=0
col=0
for key in new_dict.keys():
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row,col,   key)
    for item in new_dict[key]:
        print(item,row,col+1)
        worksheet.write(row,col + 1,item)
        col += 1
    col = 0
workbook.close()
```

However I get this output:

[image]

And I would like to have it this way:

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The values in the pictures and the given dictionary doesn't match. Is this a mistake or are you leaving out some bit of code?

Comment: there is no much difference in expected and actual . except the precision of middle column

Comment: you are getting in that way because set element is  '100.000, Oryza rufipogon x Oryza sativa' . Notice that comma (,) is present inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet()
row=0
col=0
new_dict ={'4F703:00013:02038': {'100.000 , Oryza rufipogon x Oryza sativa',
                                 '100.000 , Oryza rufipogon',
                                 '100.000 , Oryza sativa',
                                 '100.000 , Oryza sativa Japonica Group',
                                 '100.000 , Oryza sativa f. spontanea'}}
for key in new_dict.keys():
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row,col,key)
    for item in new_dict[key]:
        print(item, row, col+1)
        item = item.split(',')
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1,item[0])
        col += 1
        worksheet.write(row,col + 1,item[1])
        row += 1
        col = 0
workbook.close()
```

I think you are considering **'100.000, Oryza rufipogon x Oryza sativa'** as multiple values but its a single value and would be filled in a single column.Above solution may clear some things.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pandas.ExcelWriter` greatly simplifies this task:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'4F703:00013:02038': {'100.000, Oryza sativa', '100.000, Oryza rufipogon x Oryza sativa', '100.000, Oryza rufipogon', '100.000, Oryza sativa f. spontanea', '100.000, Oryza sativa Japonica Group'}}
new_data = [[a, [i.split(', ') for i in b]] for a, b in data.items()]
with pd.ExcelWriter('spreadsheet.xlsx') as writer:
   df = pd.DataFrame([i for a, [c, *d] in new_data for i in [[a, *c], *[['', *k] for k in d]]])
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', startrow=0, index=False)
   writer.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but with your code I don't get the values separated, they stay together...

Comment: @Sofia Is your data delimeter always `, `?

Answer (score 1):

An `item` is a string that contains a number and a text separated by a comma. That string is added to the column in the worksheet.

In order to have the number and the text separated another column is required.

You could do an `item.split(',')` and put the first part in the second column and the second part in a third one.

```
num, text = item.split(',')
worksheet.write(row,col + 1, num)
worksheet.write(row,col + 2, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no wrong in you code.

**Notice that '100.000, Oryza rufipogon x Oryza sativa'  is one value.
If you want to be as separate columns in excel. get the string and split it by , and then write it to the sheet.**